# Reuse inheritance to define a method in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I'm a new Java developer and I met some difficulties with the concept of inheritance in java to define my classes...

In one side, I have a generic class named **Vehicle** that defines a decades of attributes (with their getters/setters). And I have a **Vehicle1** class that **extends** Vehicle class.

In other side, I have a generic classe named **VehicleFactory** that defines one single static method like this :

```
public class VehicleFactory {

    protected static Vehicle makeResult() {
        Vehicle result = new Vehicle();

        result.setCode("1");
        result.setNumber("2");
        // other setters methods
        return result;
    }
```

The problem is that I want to create a **Vehicle1Factory** class with its own makeResult method that USE the makeResult method of its parent class. But I failed to do this (the aim here is the optimisation since Vehicle1 has all the generic attributes of Vehicle classe but has some additional attributes).

What I tried to write is like this :

```
public class Vehicle1Factory extends VehicleFactory {

    protected static Vehicle1 makeResult() {
        Vehicle1 result = new Vehicle1();

         result = (Vehicle1) VehicleFactory.makeResult();

        // I want to reuse the makeResult of its parent class to define
        // its own makeResult method
    }
}
```

But when I do this, Java told me that there a ClassCastException and that I can't use the cast here...

Is there any solution in that case?

Comment: What is Vehicle1? With a name like that, this class shouldn't exist. The solution is probably to use composition rather than inheritance, but your example is too unclear to say. Vehicle1Factory has no reason to exten VehicleFactory, BTW. There not even a single instance method that could be overridden in VehicleFactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once an instance of `Something` is created, it can never become an instance of something else. Since `VehicleFactory.makeResult` creates `Vehicle` instances, there's no way to transform that to `Vehicle1`.
You would have to create a `new Vehicle1` for that.

A solution can be to move the code you want to reuse to a utility method, for example:

```
class Vehicle { }

class Bike extends Vehicle { }

class VehicleFactory {
    static Vehicle create() {
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
        initialize(vehicle);
        return vehicle;
    }

    private static void initialize(Vehicle vehicle) {
        result.setCode("1");
        result.setNumber("2");
        // ...
    }
}

class BikeFactory {
    static Bike create() {
        Bike bike = new Bike();
        VehicleFactory.initialize(bike);
        return bike;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ClassCastException` occurs because you're trying to cast `Vehicle` to `Vehicle1`;

Why you can't do that? Because you can cast it in case, if the object type is `Vehicle1` under `Vehicle` reference type.

```
public class Vehicle1Factory extends VehicleFactory {

    protected static Vehicle1 makeResult() {
        // Change reference type to Vehicle 
        Vehicle result = VehicleFactory.makeResult();

        // I want to reuse the makeResult of its parent class to define
        // its own makeResult method
    }
}
```

Let's try to clarify all dark points of casting.

```
Super sub1 = new Sub(); // No casting required!
Super super1 = new Super();
Sub sub2 = new Sub();
sub2 = (Sub) sub1; // Casting required, because reference type is Super, but it's okay because real object under the reference is Sub();
sub2 = (Sub) super1(); // ClassCastException because real object is of Super type
```

The cast at the last line tells the compiler not to worry, that I'm a good programmer and I know what I am doing and the object referenced by the super class reference will actually be of class Sub at run time. So there is no compile time error. But at run time, this fails because the actual object is not an `Sub` but is `Super`.

Answer (score 0):

Since ClassCastException issue is already answered. I want to give some comments on how you are setting up your abstraction.

1) It is usually a good idea to define abstract factory concept inside abstract class.

2) I don't see point of having "protected" and "static" together. Unless your class is only to be used by subclasses and classes in the same package.

3) Extending concrete class and just using its static method does not make sense. It is usually a bad practice to mix static and inheritance together.

Anyways here is example code with cleaner abstraction definition:

```
 public class Vehicle {
    private int code = 0;
    private int number = 0;

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}

public class Vehicle1 extends Vehicle {
    private String engine = null;

    public String getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }

    public void setEngine(String engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractVehicleFactory<T extends Vehicle> {

    protected T makeVehicle() {
        T result = create();

        result.setCode(11);
        result.setNumber(24);

        return result;
    }

    protected abstract T create();
}

public class VehicleFactory extends AbstractVehicleFactory<Vehicle> {

    public static Vehicle makeResult(){
        return new VehicleFactory().makeVehicle();
    }

    @Override
    protected Vehicle makeVehicle() {
        Vehicle result = super.makeVehicle();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected Vehicle create(){
        return new Vehicle();
    }
}

public class Vehicle1Factory extends AbstractVehicleFactory<Vehicle1> {

    public static Vehicle1 makeResult(){
        return new Vehicle1Factory().makeVehicle();
    }

    @Override
    protected Vehicle1 makeVehicle() {
        Vehicle1 result = super.makeVehicle();

        result.setEngine("V8");

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected Vehicle1 create(){
        return new Vehicle1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a downcasting problem. Think that you have X and Y parameter in Vehicle but addition Z parameter in Vehicle1. Vehicle1 have all 3 of them as its the daughter of Vehicle. When you cast it to Vehicle it just hides the reference of Z but when you cast Vehicle to Vehicle1 the casting problem occurs as the Z variable is not initialized for Vehicle1.

initialize the vehicle1 in method and set the parameters. as

```
public class 

    Vehicle1Factory extends VehicleFactory {

    protected static Vehicle1 makeResult(){
        Vehicle1 result = new Vehicle1();
        Vehicle veh = (Vehicle1) VehicleFactory.makeResult();
        result.setCode(veh.getCode);
        result.setNumber(veh.getNumber);
        return result;
    }
}
```